# Local Context Map Google React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm currently trying to implement the beta version of Local Context Map from Google in my React JS app. It was working then but at some point, it just didn't. I'm not sure if it's because of the new Chrome update, since I've never checked it with other browsers before. Now, it's not displaying the map. I think it's got something to do with the lifecycle of calling the script and rendering the view. I'm really clueless now I don't know where to look anymore.

The error I'm getting is `LocalContextMapView is not defined`

This is the link for the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/local-context)

This is how I implemented it

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { defaultCenter, places, mapStyles } from '@utils/config'
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY } from '@helpers/config'

const LocalContext = ({ label, location }) => {
  let map

  const onScriptload = () => {
    let s = document.createElement('script')
    s.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&libraries=localContext&v=beta`

    document.body.appendChild(s)
    s.addEventListener('load', function () {
      initMap()
    })
  }

  function initMap() {
    const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
      element: document.getElementById('map'),
      placeTypePreferences: places,
      maxPlaceCount: 24,
    })

    map = localContextMapView.map
    new google.maps.Marker({ position: location, map: map })

    map.setOptions({
      center: location,
      zoom: 15,
      clickableIcons: true,
      styles: mapStyles,
    })

    window.map = map
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onScriptload()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="overflow-hidden">
      {label && <p className="py-5 text-3xl font-bold">{label}</p>}
      <div id="map" className="relative w-full px-10 md:px-0 h-50vh" style={{ boxSizing: 'initial' }} />
    </div>
  )
}

LocalContext.defaultProps = {
  className: 'h-80',
}

LocalContext.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  location: PropTypes.object,
}

export default LocalContext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there's something that makes the `LocalContextMapView` to be called before the script was fully loaded. I can implement the Local Context in react by tweaking your `onScriptLoad`. I put a condition that will check if the script is loaded by adding a `script-loaded` attribute in the script.

```
  const onScriptload = () => {
    var gScript = document.querySelector("script-loaded");
    var isLoaded = gScript && gScript.getAttribute("script-loaded");

    if (!isLoaded) {
      var index = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src =
        "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=localContext&v=beta&callback=initialize";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.setAttribute("script-loaded", true);
      index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
      window.initialize = initMap;
    } else {
      initMap();
    }
  };
```

Here is the full code snippet and the [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/localcontext-react-3u4tyw?file=Map.js):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
const LocalContext = () => {
  let map;

  const onScriptload = () => {
    var gScript = document.querySelector("script-loaded");
    var isLoaded = gScript && gScript.getAttribute("script-loaded");

    if (!isLoaded) {
      var index = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src =
        "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=localContext&v=beta&callback=initialize";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.setAttribute("script-loaded", true);
      index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
      window.initialize = initMap;
    } else {
      initMap();
    }
  };

  function initMap() {
    const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView(
      {
        element: document.getElementById("map"),
        placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction"],
        maxPlaceCount: 12
      }
    );

    map = localContextMapView.map;
    map.setOptions({
      center: { lat: 51.507307, lng: -0.08114 },
      zoom: 14
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onScriptload();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="overflow-hidden">
      <div id="map" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LocalContext;
```

Comment: God! It did work!!! You're a genius!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend usage of one of the two packages [@googlemaps/js-api-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader) and a useEffect hook or [@googlemaps/react-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/react-wrapper)(uses @googlemaps/js-api-loader internally).

```js
import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";

const MyApp = () => (
  <Wrapper apiKey={"YOUR_API_KEY"} libraries={['localcontext']}>
    <LocalContext />
  </Wrapper>
);
```

The [internals](https://github.com/googlemaps/react-wrapper/blob/5f5ae50dc6f81ef2376f25960698322b00268e2e/src/index.tsx#L66) of the @googlemaps/react-wrapper are quite trivial if you want more control with the useEffect hook.

Comment: Hi justin! Thanks for taking time to answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `callback` param in the query string pointing to a function in the window so that when the scripts finish loading, the callback function will be invoked. `script.addEventListener('load')` will not work because the initial script will load few other scripts so the `initMap` function should be called after everything is finished loading.

Also make sure to set the #map height explicitly to define the size of the div element that contains the map.

```js
// initMap should be defined as a global function in the window
window.initMap = function initMap() {}
```